# Implement a 3-input function using only two 2-input LUTs

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, optimization

This is my homework: "Given the function \$f(x_1, x_2,x_3) = \sum (2,3,4,6,7)\$ Show how it can be realized using two 2-input LUTs. Give the truth table implemented in each LUT."

At  the beginning it seems very simple, but this is a beast! I don't want you to solve it, but just show me a way to come up with a general formula to solve these kinds of LUT optimization problems.

I only know that an n-input LUT can be used to implement a \$ 2^n\$ input function, so in this case we have 3 inputs so we need a 3-input LUT. Meanwhile if we are forced to use 2-input LUT, then I can see that we can divide the function output values into two LUTs with \$x_1, x_2\$ as their inputs, and then put a MUX with \$x_3\$ as its selector to produce  the function \$f\$. But in this problem we are not allowed to use the MUX, but only two 2-input LUTs. How  can it be?!

Comment: Have you tried using Karnaugh diagrams? This might simplify your function quite radically. After that you could use de Morgan's law and other laws to get a function you want

Comment: This problem is not about function optimization. It is about implementation of a function using LUTs with constraints.

Comment: ... which is the same problem, @Ehsan.

Comment: For example, 2,3, 6 and 7 look like could be grouped and written by two or even one variable which would make everything so much easier, wouldn't it?

Comment: No. In LUT implementation, optimization do not have an effect on the number of LUTs being used. There is no need for Boolean optimization here.

Comment: @Ehsan combining multiple LUTs **is** a function, and the question  on how to select the cases the individual LUTs should cover is function optimization, and Arturas recommended the usual way of doing that.

Comment: You have three variables which could be divided into five different groups. That would mean that if you had logic devices which 3 inputs, you would still need at least more than 5 devices. Of course, go ahead, use several tenths of devices, use it whenever you can, that would not make a cost higher. To get the best result you have to optimize your function first. I'm pretty sure you'll need three or four devices at most. I could even show you how it's done

Comment: I am sure both of you are getting this wrong. To prove me wrong you should give me the zeros and ones for LUT0 and LUT1 that can implement the given function, and also do mention the connection configuration between the two LUTs.

Comment: @Ehsan which is equivalent to do your homework. I'd have a word for that behaviour, but it's not nice, so I'm not going to use that.

Comment: @Ehsan also, we'd just be applying what Arturas said in his first comment

Comment: I can easily apply k-map and get: \$f = x_2 + x_3x_1' \$ But I can not see the point behind getting an optimized Boolean algebra really.

Comment: @Ehsan excellent, now we're making progress. can you implement `a+b` and `a · (not b)` as a 2-LUT?

Comment: Yes for \(a+b\) I just need to program my LUT as [0,1,1,1]. and for \(a . b'\) I just need to program my LUT as [0,0,1,0]. But what is the point ?

Comment: oh I see the point now ! lol ok I accept your answer just put this in answer section: 1) Optimize 2)Apply LUT to optimized expression and get a beautiful +10 points.

Comment: No! It does not work! Do you feed the LUT0 output  to an input of LUT1 ?

Comment: @Ehsan - Yes I believe you finally got it. The two LUTs need to be used in a cascaded logic configuration.